# Is there a rust equivalent of onProgramAccountChange()?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-client

What I am trying to do is listen to some onchain program accounts being changed. I could do this pretty easily in typescript with onProgramAccountChange() method provided in the Connection class in @solana/web3.js package. Is there a way to do this in rust, as I cannot find any impl in rust's solana_client crate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

You have to use the `PubsubClient`

```
solana_client::{
        nonblocking::pubsub_client::PubsubClient,
};
```

This is the method you want:

```
  pub async fn account_subscribe(
        &self,
        pubkey: &Pubkey,
        config: Option<RpcAccountInfoConfig>,
    ) -> SubscribeResult<'_, RpcResponse<UiAccount>> {
        let params = json!([pubkey.to_string(), config]);
        self.subscribe("account", params).await
    }
```